# Calling ipn paypal, PayumBundle

Tags: symfony, payum

I have problems with paypal calling the notification function, i think i have everything set up correctly, however there is little documentation available about this

```
use Maxim\CMSBundle\Entity\NotificationDetails;
use Payum\Action\ActionInterface;
use Payum\Request\NotifyTokenizedDetailsRequest;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use Maxim\CMSBundle\Entity\Visitor;

class StoreNotificationAction implements ActionInterface
{
    protected $doctrine;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine, $logger) {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->logger   = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function execute($request)
    {
        /** @var NotifyTokenizedDetailsRequest $request */
        $this->logger->err("hi");
        $notification = new NotificationDetails;
        $notification->setPaymentName($request->getTokenizedDetails()->getPaymentName());
        $notification->setDetails($request->getNotification());
        $notification->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime);
        $this->doctrine->getManager()->persist($notification);

        $this->doctrine->getManager()->flush();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function supports($request)
    {
        return $request instanceof NotifyTokenizedDetailsRequest;
    }
}
```

which i am calling with a service defined in services.yml and also this is my configuration according to the git example:

```
payum:
    contexts:
        paypal_express_checkout_plus_doctrine:
            paypal_express_checkout_nvp:
                api:
                    options:
                        username:  'MYUSER'
                        password:  'MYPAS'
                        signature: 'MYSIGNATURE'
                        sandbox: true
                actions:
                    - myname.action.store_notification
            storages:
                myname\mybundle\Entity\PaypalExpressPaymentDetails:
                    doctrine:
                        driver: orm
                        payment_extension: true
                myname\mybundle\Entity\TokenizedDetails:
                    doctrine:
                        driver: orm
                        payment_extension: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you correctly setup NOTIFY_URL. For this you have to generate tokenForNotifyRoute and use its targetUrl as notify. See an example of [prepareAction](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundleSandbox/blob/master/src/Acme/PaypalExpressCheckoutBundle/Controller/PurchaseExamplesController.php#L186) in the sandbox.

Comment: Please note that you also has to add notify route https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundleSandbox/blob/master/app/config/routing.yml#L18

Comment: You could also do basic validation with this small lib https://github.com/Payum/PaypalIpn

Comment: All of the above is set, none of them seem to be the issue

Comment: sandbox could produce huge delays or even not respond. Where simulator or live works fine. For more info read the blog: http://www.arronwoods.com/blog/2008/09/paypal-ipn-from-the-sandbox-not-working/

and issue on github https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/issues/45#issuecomment-23991318

Comment: Do you know if this sends the data back to paypal to 'validate' as in this section: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#id08CKFJ00JYK or must this be done manually?

Comment: Not it is not, but it is not really required, as the notiyurl contains a hash which nobody aware of, and secondly nothing from notify url is used to decided a payment status, instead a separate call is done to paypal, and it returns correct data, which can trust.